# Wrong category being displayed in URL

Tags: categories

I'm a newbie to wordpress so please bear with me. I have two categories I'm using, basketball and baseball. I've only recently added the baseball category and if I add a new post with category baseball, in the URL, the post displays /basketball/post-name regardless of what I do. I've changed the permalinks settings and played with some plugins as well, and I've checked to make sure my SEO plugin isn't messing with these things.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: And when you're viewing the edit screen for that post, are you 100% sure that you only have "baseball" checked in the categories for that post?

Comment: To better understand your problem please Could you send me your URL ?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee, I've checked this countless times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just an update: I used the plugin WP Permastructure to solve the issue by adding /%category%/%postname%/ in the "category" section on the bottom of the permalinks settings page (the permalink adds new fields). Not really sure why this works but changing the permalink structure normally does not.